# How to set effect volume in cocos2d android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am new in cocos2d android.
In my game, I used following code in game setting.

```
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().setEffectsVolume(volume);
```

> where, volume is float in range of (0.0 to 1.0).

But, there is no change in effect volume.
Please give solution of it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you get any error , If not then check one thing that is SoundEngine.sharedEngine().setEffectsVolume(volume); it gives some response  on your logcat or not .....

Comment: in my time ... it works fine .... put some code related to this after we'll sort this thing